For which $a$ does $f_n(x) = \frac{x(1-x^2)^n}{n^a}, n=1,2,3,...$ converge pointwise and uniformly on $[0,1]$?
For which $a$ does $f_n(x) = \frac{x(1-x^2)^n}{n^a}, n=1,2,3,...$ converge pointwise and uniformly on $[0,1]$?
I start with $\lim_{{n \to \infty}}f_n(x) = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{x(1-x^2)^n}{n^a} = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} x \cdot \lim_{{n \to \infty}}(1-x^2)^n \cdot \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n^a}$.

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} x = x$,

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}}(1-x^2)^n = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x \in (0,1]
\end{cases}$,

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n^a} = \begin{cases}
+\infty & \text{if } a < 0 \\
1 & \text{if } a = 0 \\
0 & \text{if } a > 0
\end{cases}$


This gives me 6 cases:

$x = 0 \text{ and } a < 0 \implies \lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n = \frac{0 \cdot 1}{+\infty} = 0$,

$x = 0 \text{ and } a = 0 \implies \lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n = \frac{0 \cdot 1}{1} = 0$,

$x = 0 \text{ and } a > 0 \implies \lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n = \frac{0 \cdot 1}{0} = \text{not defined?}$,

$x \in (0,1] \text{ and } a < 0 \implies \lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n = \frac{x \cdot 0}{+\infty} = 0$,

$x \in (0,1] \text{ and } a = 0 \implies \lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n = \frac{x \cdot 0}{1} = 0$,

$x \in (0,1] \text{ and } a > 0 \implies \lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n = \frac{x \cdot 0}{0} = \text{not defined?}$.


First, are case 3. and case 6. not defined or am I doing something wrong here?
Intuitively I want to say that the sequence of functions $f_n$ converge for all $a \leq 0$, however for pointwise convergence I thought $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} f_n$ needed to be a function dependent on $x$, am I wrong? How do I go from my list of cases to proving pointwise and uniform convergence?
Thank you.

$0 \le f_n(x)\le n^{-a}$ and this is enough to conclude that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly when  $a>0$.

@geetha290krm how so?
